# Gatling - Split Value In Check

Tags: css, scala, gatling

I have a HTML element from a HTTP request like so:

```
<input type="radio" data-trip="0" id="fareRadioId_" name="pricefare" value="H15CNGE~SHATSA~220420150955~3332|H15CNGE~TSASHA~270420150715~338" class="pricefare" data-toggle="radio" checked="checked">
```

I'm used to pulling a value from a CSS select like so:

```
.check(css("input#fareRadioId_0.select_departure", "value").saveAs("departSellKey"))
```

But after I've selected the value in the element above which is "H15CNGE~SHATSA~220420150955~3332|H15CNGE~TSASHA~270420150715~338", I want to split it in to parts, with the split character being "|", and save the two parts in to session with 2 different names. Is this possible?

I've pretty new to Gatling and Scala so this is a little above my head at the moment. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if you'll be able to save the two parts with different names, but it's fairly easy to perform the split and store the result as a `Seq`, after which you can access it with indexes etc.

What you need to do is insert a suitable [transformer](http://gatling.io/docs/2.0.0-RC5/cheat-sheet.html) into your check:

```
.check(css("...").transform(_.split('|').toSeq).saveAs("sellKeys"))
```

This takes the `String` from the `css()` expression, does a `split()` on it (which creates an `Array[String]`) and then converts it to a `Seq` because they're nicer to work with :-)

The `Seq` is then saved into `sellKeys`, so later on you can do things like (silly example):

```
 .exec( session => {
    val keys = session("sellKeys").as[Seq[String]]
    println(s"keys are ${keys.mkString(" and ")}")
    println(s"the first key is ${keys.head}") 
    session 
    }
)
```

Output:

```
keys are H15CNGE~SHATSA~220420150955~3332 and H15CNGE~TSASHA~270420150715~338
the first key is H15CNGE~SHATSA~220420150955~3332
```

Comment: Thank you so much millhouse. I've not ventured in to transformers yet, very handy indeed.